# org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl is closed

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee, transactions

I have this function in my dao that check of login:

```
public User checkLogin(String login, String password) {
        Transaction transaction = null;
        User user = null;
        try (Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession()) {
            transaction = session.beginTransaction();
            Query query=session.createQuery("from User where login=:login and password=:password");
            query.setParameter("login", login);
            query.setParameter("password", password);
            user=(User) query.getSingleResult();
            transaction.commit();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            if (transaction != null) {
                transaction.rollback();
            }
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return user;
    }
```

but for some reason I'm getting this exception:

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl@4804aa89 is close`

The exemption comes from the `transaction.rollback();` part.

How can I solve this ?

**Edit:**

Thanks to @Mar-Z answer I moved  `ex.printStackTrace` before rollbacking the transaction, and the actual error was :

`Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: User is not mapped`

So I updated my code with this:

`Query query=session.createQuery("from User where login=:login and password=:password", User.class);`

which didn't solve the thrown exception.

Comment: First move the line with ex.printStackTrace up to get the actual cause of the issue. Then you can decide about what to do next. Maybe you should put the rollback line in another try/catch block and only log the error and ignore the exception. Because rollback on a closed connection doesn't hurt much.

Comment: @Mar-Z can you please check  my edit ?

Comment: User is not mapped means there is no entity class with the name User. Check this please. In doubts share the code. Important thing is also the package. It needs to be scanned by Hibernate. Check also the annotation @EntityScan.